# How can I use rules to grab fields from one content type to another then delete the old nodes?

Tags: rules, views

I have an D7 site using feeds that create dozens of nodes daily populated with RSS articles. I use the body fields from these articles as well so I can read them on-site without clicking to the actual publisher. Means my database is getting bigger. Here's what I want to do:

Any node over 4 weeks old of 'feed' type needs to create a new node called 'feed archive' and do this by using the old title and just the article URL - no other fields need to be transferred. Then the old node can be deleted. So I basically dump all the body content and other fields attached to the old 'feed' node and just leave the title and URL and create a new node with these two things.

I have created a rule using VBO views before so kind of understand that, but don't know how I say: 'create a new node, only grab these two fields from it, then delete it'

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your rule, i think your can write a custom php code:

```
  //$node is your original node

  $node_new = new stdClass();
  $node_new->type = 'content_type_2';
  $node_new->status = 1;
  $node_new->uid = $node->uid;
  $node_new->title = $node->title;
  $node_new->promote = 0;
  $node_new->created = $node->created;
  $node_new->timestamp = $node->timestamp;
  $node_new->field_article_url = $node->field_article_url;

  node_save( $node_new );
  node_delete( $node );
```

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying that I loop over the VBO to grab the nodes that over 4 weeks old - then run this php on that list? Sorry, not an expert with code.

Comment: yes if you want to use VBO with an UI. My opinion is that this king of code should be inserted in a hook_cron without UI (no VBO) and should run alone.